# Shuffle Array function yields same result

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

This is a down and dirty vanilla javascript question. I'm using a classic array shuffle function:

```
  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }
```

And then calling it repeatedly in another function:

```
  function generateQuartile (array) {

    var shuffle1 = shuffle(array);

    var shuffle2 = shuffle(array);

    var shuffle3 = shuffle(array);

    //all three shuffles are the same 

  }
```

The problem is, all three of those variables are yielding the same result. The array is shuffled once, and then not again. I can't seem to pin down what this is. I'm guessing it's some sort of scoping/hoisting problem but I really can't figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shuffling is working correctly. The problem is that you're returning the same array each time. At each call, you need to make a new array with the randomized elements. The easiest thing would be to clone the array right at the start of the function:

```
array = array.slice();
```

With that change, `shuffle1`, `shuffle2`, and `shuffle3` will be three distinct arrays. Also, the original array will not be modified; that may be either a good or bad thing, depending on your design.

Alternatively, you can leave your `shuffle` function alone and clone each return value:

```
var shuffle1 = shuffle(array).slice();
// etc.
```

Comment: that totally worked - but I still don't get how I'm returning the same array... the while loop runs on each call, and the randomization happens, so why wouldn't the array be updated :/

Comment: @LukeSchunk - It's updating the _elements_ of the array, but the array itself is still the same object, so when you change it on each call, all the references see the same object change..

Comment: because arrays are references in javascript? so it's not mutating anything?

Comment: @LukeSchunk - Exactly. In JavaScript (unlike C++, say), variables are never themselves objects; they are only references to objects (or they are primitive values). All objects are "on the heap" (so to speak).